# Doctrine Query builder, return dates by year and month, ignore day

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I have date in table in this format 2015-06-06.
But I need to search database by only two params: Year and month.

I'm new to Doctrine, so I have no idea how should I do that. I used active-record.

Comment: Please show a code example

Answer (score 0):

use mysql `YEAR()` and `MONTH()`

```
select * from table year(date)='2015' and MONTH(date)='03'
```

> MySQL YEAR() returns the year for a given date
>
> MySQL MONTH() returns the MONTH for the date within a range of 1 to 12

Comment: How that should look in query builder? Thanks

Comment: select * from your_table_name year('2015-06-06')='2015' and MONTH('2015-06-06')='06'

Comment: its not required to have 2 digits for month - 06 can be just 6 and it can be integer without ''

Answer (score 0):

If you are using query builder just add :

```
 ->where('YEAR(x.date) = ?', $year)
```

or

```
 ->where('MONTH(x.date) = ?', $month)
```

Where $year and $month are digits and x.date is your table date field.